# NullPointer exception in setAdapter in ListView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter

when wifi is on - all works, but when it off - i get nullPointer exception

```
package ua.khuta.myskidka;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FragmentNews extends Fragment {
private View v;
ListView lvNews;
Database db;
mySCadapter scAdapter;
public String DEBUG_TAG = "myLogs";
String[] from = new String[] { Database.NEWS_TITLE, Database.NEWS_IMAGE_URL,
        Database.NEWS_SHORT_DESCRIPTION };
int [] to = new int[] { R.id.item_news_tv_title, R.id.item_news_iv_image,
        R.id.item_news_tv_short_description };



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, null);
    lvNews = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_new);
    lvNews.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = Database.getInstance(getActivity());

    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "wi-fi is on");
        db.cleanDB();
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    } else {

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "wi-fi is off");

        Cursor c = db.getNewsFromDb();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
         mySCadapter scAdapter = new mySCadapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_news, c,
                from, to);

        lvNews.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    }

}



class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Creating JSON Parser instance

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        Cursor c = db.getNewsFromDb();
        scAdapter = new mySCadapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_news, c,
                from, to);

        lvNews.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

ErrorLog

```
    10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.khuta.myskidka/ua.khuta.myskidka.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at ua.khuta.myskidka.FragmentNews.onCreate(FragmentNews.java:82)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-10 09:12:53.275: E/AndroidRuntime(28582):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: waht is line 82 `FragmentNews.java`?

Comment: lvNews.setAdapter(scAdapter);

Comment: in this part: else {

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "wi-fi is off");

        Cursor c = db.getNewsFromDb();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
         mySCadapter scAdapter = new mySCadapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_news, c,
                from, to);

        lvNews.setAdapter(scAdapter);
    }

Comment: lvNews is null. check it

Comment: @Raghunandan I disagree. Check his onCreateView

Comment: @KostyaKhuta are you sure about the line? Maybe is the cursor null?

Comment: @blackbelt its `onCreate` then `onCreateView` right? in `onCreate` layout in not inflated right?

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right. Only now I realize that he is calling it inside onCreate and not onActivityCreated. You should post an answer (maybe you could explain him the Fragment lifecycle)

Comment: i check
if (lvNews==null) it is true. Why my lvNews is null?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes your are right first OnCreate is exicute that's y that error

Comment: @blackbelt someone beat me and already posted it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that you are creating your ListView in `onCreateView()` and setting its `adapter` in `onCreate()` ..

you should know that `onCreate()` is always called before `onCreateView()` and by that time your `listview` is not being created .. thats why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Place your code of `onCreate()` in `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have created your `ListView` on `onCreateView()` method, and you have set adapter in `onCreate()`. So `onCreate()` must be called before `onCreateView()`, that's why `ListViews` is not initialized, and you have found null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating your *ListView* in another layout file while you are calling any other layout file in same activity .So its mismatch in layout calling the activity.So place *ListView* in same layout that your activity using or if you want *ListView* in another layout then change *ArrayAdapter* object **context** e.g.:
**change it to**

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout., R.id., );

**with this:**

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(,
                R.layout., R.id., );

Answer (score 0):

Just put your listview code on **`onViewCreated`** callback

Try this code:

```
Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);    
}

@Override 
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    try 
    {
        // put your codes here
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) overrided method and try placing your code in that. It will help to fix this crash.Because creating view before it exists produces this exception and crashes your application.using onPause() and onResume() whenever you move from this view reduces crash too.